# Probability space associated with a compact group

Tags: measure-theory, topological-groups

Is the probability space associated with a compact group with Haar probability always a standard probability space? I recall seeing somewhere the fact that if the topology generating the Borel sigma algebra is not metrizable then the probability space is not standard, or something along these lines. If so then any non-metrizable compact group would show the answer to the above question to be negative, but I am unable to find any firm reference for the above fact. Any help with answering the above question would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please, formulate a notion of a "standard probability space".

Comment: Sorry for the lack of precision. I had in mind the definition from Rokhlin's original [work](http://ma.huji.ac.il/~matang02/rohlin.pdf). There the term used is "Lebesgue space", and as stated bottom of page 14, these are measure spaces that are separable and complete mod 0 with respect to their bases. (On the web I find "standard probability space" and "Lebesgue–Rokhlin probability space" used for the same notion)

Comment: Thank you very much for Rokhlin's original work.